# c# Html agility pack HtmlDocument does not contain all Elements from the website

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

at the time I´m making a chatbot. The bot should be able to define a word, so I tried getting the span Element from Google (https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHBD_deDE721DE721&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20test) where the definition is writen in, wich didn't work. It turns out that the htmlDocument does not contain the hole website.

```
    string Url = "https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome- instant&rlz=1C1CHBD_deDE721DE721&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20test";
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);
    HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='uid_0']/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/ol/li[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/span");
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(node.InnerText))
        output += node.InnerText;
```

node is not set to an Instance of an object

I let me give the InnerHtml of the document and put it in a gist: https://gist.github.com/MarcelBulpr/bb44a527d8202eb7fffb4e21fb8b4fed

it seems that the website does not load the result of the search request.

Does anyone know how to work around this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The post is missing [MCVE] (if actual HTML does have data and you just can't get selector right - VTC for this reason), or this is the same as plenty of "why HTMLAgilityPack does not run JavaScript to render full page" questions. Please investigate which one it is and [edit] the post accordingly.

Comment: The example I gave is the minimal code needet to run and reproduce the Problem. I also gave the Website where i want to take it from (and yes the xPath I used exists). I asked for a work around and that the page is not loading the response is just an assumtion. Also i defined the Problem and gave as much Info as i could. What is missing in your eyes? I'ill be happy to add more information if you can clarify.

Comment: I recommend reading through existing posts - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping+c%23 ... and getting some HTTP debugger like Fiddler (or use built in browser's dev tools) to see actual HTTP responses. Note that asking others to perform actions that potentially against particular site policy is not nice at best (in real world asking others to perform illegal activity could be even considered criminal activity by itself) - so you really should figure out details yourself and make question self-contained.